# Decoding Jwt in Blazore Client_side results WASM: System.ArgumentException: IDX12723: Unable to decode the payload '[PII is hidden

Tags: .net, jwt, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

Im trying to decode a Jwt generated by my asp.net core api 
this is the code i use to decode my jwt

```
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenS = handler.ReadJwtToken(jwt);
        return tokenS;
```

This works in server. no problem. 
But if i try to use the same piece of code in Blazor client_side i get this error.

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: System.ArgumentException: IDX12723: Unable to decode the payload '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' as Base64Url encoded string. jwtEncodedString: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a default constructor to use for type System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload. Path 'unique_name', line 1, position 15.

this is the jwt token im using and trying to decode

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IjA4ZDdjYzE5LWY2OTgtYTRlOS05ODcxLWE2ZWM1ODg1OTRhZCIsInJvbGUiOiJBZG1pbiIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJvY2xpY2swMjEiLCJuYmYiOjE1ODQ4MjM0MTYsImV4cCI6MTU4NDgyMzcxNiwiaWF0IjoxNTg0ODIzNDE2fQ.nD3YzBu1qvNelDz2WHcMSGcKkTtTHX98baNTBXeu12M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK for anybody who has this problem later. please dont be like me and first read the error. 
so for more details i turned the PII on.
just put this line of code before error causing line.

```
   IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
```

now i could see a better detail of my problem this was the error after turning my PII on

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a default
>   constructor to use for type System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload

And after a little bit searching i this was my solution

Put this line of code in Program.cs after builder.Build(); like this

```
      var host = builder.Build();
        _ = new JwtPayload();
```

BOOM error is gone and you can deserialize your jwt and make awesome things.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more?
Especially where is this program.cs found?

And what kind of variable is builder?

Because I'm having the same issue on a HoloLens device.

Comment: @Spoon Hi, I dont understand what do you mean by issue on HoloLens. Are you trying to use the SDK of Hololens to develop an app for this device? 
program.cs is initiation file for a c# application in .net core environment. you can read more about it in MSDN website.

Comment: So I'm facing the same issue on a HoloLens device where my device is "Unable to find a default constructor to use for type System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload".
The question here is where exactly did you include the line: "_ = new JwtPayload();"?

Comment: Every C# .net core application starts with a Program.cs.
In Some older version of .net such as .net 5 or .net 3.1 Program.cs will call a Startup.Cs file to construct and configure the application. this file could be a good place to put the payload in. 
I think its better for you to create a post so other people can also see it.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify @saeed-asgari's answer, `IdentityModelEventSource` is a class in the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging` namespace / package. Obviously this is a static member so it only needs to be set once. But for my purpose, I only needed this to be set true during a debug session (on encountering this problem), so I did this as follows: manually setting `_debug_showPII`  to true while debugging (or better: commenting this out once no longer needed):

```
try {
    bool _debug_showPII = false;
    if(_debug_showPII)
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    ClaimsPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(...)
    //...
}
catch(Exception ex) { /*...*/ }
```

I started getting this exception after updating a bunch of dependencies (from roughly .NET 6 to .NET 8), including some JWT related types, I may just need to update some other dependencies to fix this. That said, the error I was getting was also related to JSON deserialization, though I'm not currently sure why it should be a problem:

```
IDX12723: Unable to decode the payload 'eyJ...'* as Base64Url encoded string.

IDX11023: Expecting json reader to be positioned on 'JsonTokenType.String or JsonTokenType.StartArray', reader was positioned at: 'Number', Reading: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload', Position: '41', CurrentDepth: '1', BytesConsumed: '47'.
```

- Note: despite the claim of unable to parse Base64Url, #1 this token is purely alpha-numeric, and #2: it clearly was valid base64Url encoding. Proof being this was a unit test, and the string hasn't changed, which worked for years prior to this bump of versions.

UPDATE: This particular problem in my case was fixed by updating the package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` from `7.0.3` to `7.1.2`. In Nuget, `7.0.3` was listed as having some kind of vulnerability, I wonder if this was just a bug (though that version was fine before other dependencies were updated).

```
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.1.2" />
```